How jnana marga works?
I wonder a person who did bad deeds can attain liberation through Jnana marga.
Jnana marga irrespective of their good or bad Karma should attain moksha otherwise it will become karma marga then that person becomes karma yogi and not jnana yogi.
My question is if everything works as per their karma then what decides a person to be Jnana yogi?

Through jnana marg, you realise you are not a limited human being. You never were. Karma will do its job as usual for that human being.

If I understood your question, the answer might be in the second chapter of the Geeta, Sānkhya Yog. The process mentioned is to discard all selfish desires and cravings of the senses, remain undisturbed amidst misery, neither delighted by good fortune nor dejected by tribulation, subdue the senses, and keep the mind absorbed in Me. In the end, Shree Krishna says: "One who has restrained the senses from their objects, O mighty-armed Arjun, is firmly established in transcendental knowledge." These can be achieved only through knowledge; no act or karma is needed.
